# Xcode UIPickerView "NSInvalidArgumentExpression"?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, uipickerview

I'm trying to implement a UIPickerView in a FlipsideViewController, which is just a settings tab.

Here's the relevant code in the .h file:

```
@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *Categories;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *categoriesData;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* dataArray;

- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;

- (NSInteger)Categories:(UIPickerView *)Categories numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;

- (NSString*)Categories:(UIPickerView *)Categories titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Here's the relevant code in the .m file:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     _Categories = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((pickerWidth*4/3)/2-pickerWidth/2, 50.0f, pickerWidth, 200.0f)];

        _Categories.showsSelectionIndicator = true;

        [_Categories selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

        [self.view addSubview: _Categories];

        _dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [_dataArray addObject:@"One"];
        [_dataArray addObject:@"Two"];
        [_dataArray addObject:@"Three"];
        [_dataArray addObject:@"Four"];
        [_dataArray addObject:@"Five"];

        _categoriesData = _dataArray;

         _Categories.dataSource = (id)self;

         _Categories.delegate = (id)self;

}

- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)Categories
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)Categories:(UIPickerView *)Categories numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return _categoriesData.count;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)Categories:(UIPickerView *)Categories titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_categoriesData objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Sorry if that's a little too much to read. The point is that in the final portion, when `- (NSInteger)Categories:(UIPickerView *)Categories numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component` is run, it returns a "NSInvalidArgumentException". I tried reinitializing the dataArray and categoriesData in each method, to no avail. I'm not sure what I should do... please help. Thanks!

EDIT:

Found the error. It was in the method call... instead of specifying which UIPickerView I was trying to access, I instead should have just put in a generic "UIPickerView". So, it should've looked like this:

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{}
```

and not like this:

```
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)Categories titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)Categories numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{}
```

Hope this helps anyone finding a similar problem.

Comment: Is "NSInvalidArgumentException" the full error message?

Comment: @Zaph No. The full message is: "_Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FlipsideViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd374cac3b0'_". That's how I know it's in the numberOfRowsInComponent method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like categoriesData is not assigning the value properly. Try to change this line below and check:-

```
self.categoriesData = _dataArray;
```

Comment: No dice. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you try returning some other value inside your method??

Comment: Yeah, I tried "return 5" and "return @"Hi""... not working either. Perhaps my understanding of pickerView is deficient in some way, so I'll continue picking at it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then the issue is in your method. Please check that.